# Is there a difference between using the return value of UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject and the exported object?

Tags: java, rmi

When exporting an object I find that both this

```
LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);
ObjectToExport obj = new ObjectToExport();
UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(obj, 1099);
Naming.rebind("ObjectName", obj);
```

and this

```
LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);
ObjectToExport obj = new ObjectToExport();
Naming.rebind("ObjectName", UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(obj, 1099));
```

work. In the first I don't use the return value of `exportObject` and in the second I do. Is there a difference between these 2 ways of exporting an object? 
The API only says that the return value is the `remote object stub`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference at the export step, but you're also binding the object, and there's a difference at this step. In the first step you're passing the actual object; in the second, the stub. *However* the semantics of RMI are that exported remote objects are passed to remote methods as their own stubs, so the actual effect at the Registry is the same.